# Send data from another website to flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Is it possible send data from a website to flutter website and take data with GET or POST like PHP?
In PHP we can take data with GET or POST. Let's say we are sending data to data.php and we are getting with below sample code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET)) {
    echo "GET<br/>";
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    echo $data;
}
echo "<br/>";
if (isset($_POST)) {
    echo "POST<br/>";
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    echo $data;
}
if (!isset($_GET) || !isset($_POST)) {
    echo "no data";
}
?>
```

I want to get data like this. Is it possible? Thank you...